# How to assign a hardware button to camera

Tags: camera, buttons

I like the functionality of a hardware camera button. On my Lumia 920 I have a dedicated camera button that I can long-press at any time (in other apps or when the phone is locked) to open the camera app in 1-2 seconds.

I also have a Galaxy Note 1 (JB, rooted) without such hardware button. Is there a way to reconfigure one of the existing hardware buttons (e.g. long-press volume up) to always open the camera app even while the screen is locked?

Comment: Since you are rooted, what ROM are you running?

Comment: @VarnerBeast14 : I'm using the stock Samsung ROM. (4.1.2) I hope I won't have to flash a custom ROM for this but I'm willing to try if I can't find another solution.

Comment: You might not have to, but I know that a lot of the custom ROMs have the ability to set hardware actions. Just something you might want to look into if you have no other options.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve what you want to do with the help of [Home2 Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eikatou0.appspot.home2shortcut). The app is self-explanatory. You can easily use it.

If you have enables S Voice on double-tap, go into the S Voice settings and uncheck the Launch SVoice box. This will keep S Voice from launching when you double tap the home button.

Open Home2 Shortcut and configure it to launch the app of your choosing with a double tap of the home button. When you get to the end, after you tap "close" it will ask you to set as default. Select Home2Launcher as the default.

<sup>Read more information [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=29149396&postcount=1).</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem to work for me while the screen is locked though.