# Camera app that can use hardware buttons for making photo

Tags: camera, buttons, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I am searching for either a camera app with hardware button support, or for some other solution that would make it possible to use hardware buttons for **making photo** (shutter) in a camera app.

My phone, Samsung Galaxy S III mini doesn't have separate camera button, only power button, home button, back and menu buttons, and volume rocker.  It is IMHO much easier to use hardware button than to try to hit software button on camera screen.

I think this should be possible, because built-in Phone Call app can be configured to accept call with Home button, and end / cancel the call with Power button.

---

This question can be considered to be continuation of [How to assign a hardware button to camera](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/48388/43152) which is about using hardware button (e.g. Home) to ***start*** camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While *Is there an app for X* questions are off-topic here, just a little hint: You might wish to take a look at [ProCapture](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ProCapture-Free/com.neaststudios.procapture.free) and [A Better Camera](http://www.appbrain.com/app/A-Better-Camera/com.almalence.opencam), which both support the volume rocker for either shutter or zoom (configurable). I'm pretty sure they are not the only ones.

Comment: Well, usually you can just search marketplace or one of app recommendation pages for *Is there an app for X* answer, but it is hard to search for side-issues such as making use of hardware buttons.

Comment: "A Better Camera" can use volume rocker for shutter, but it cannot use Home or Power button for that, and with flip cover volume rocker is less accessible. I'd really like to use volume rocker for zoom, and power button for shutter...

Comment: Though there might be such apps as well, I didn't say *these two* can make use of all buttons ;) I know there are apps to re-design button behavior, but as I already wrote: *Is there an app for X* questions are off-topic here (see our [help/on-topic] if you don't believe me; it's also hard to compare device specs, still device/shopping recommendations are off-topic as well). Generally, better describe the *problem* you want to solve. For this Q, it could be re-phrased to "How can I use hardware buttons to shoot a photo (or zoom in/out)", which is why it wasn't put "on hold".

Answer (score 1):

The [Camera ZOOM FX Premium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=slide.cameraZoom) support setting actions for hardware buttons and gestures, e.g. volume to control zoom, or to shoot photo.  Note that free version doesn't support hardware buttons mapping.

I guess that both power button and home button are available only to system/root apps (like built-in Phone Call app).