# How to use volume key to take picture in Samsung S3 (with android 4.2)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.2-jelly-bean

I've just been gave a Samsung S3, and it come with Android 4.2 (so I cant apply this [guide](http://inside-galaxy.blogspot.com/2013/12/samsung-galaxy-s3-how-to-take-picture.html)) So I post this question, Please guide me how to take picture using volume key with Samsung S3 (Android 4.2)!?

Comment: Is the device rooted? You can use [Xposed Additions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb) then. If not, see if [QuickClick](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blor.quickclickgold) helps. On a side note, how do you want to assign volume key to camera app? In a way that pressing it would awake the device and launch the camera app for you, then you could use it take snapshot as well? Or, in a way, the device is already awake (screen is active), camera app is already opened and you press the Volume key to take a snapshot?..

Comment: For the latter case, related:[Camera app that can use hardware buttons for making photo](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/57412)

Comment: @Firelord cause if you can not take the picture with volume key, you can not use the selfie stick to take picture too. 
Candy Camera or some other camera app can do this, but I dont want to install other camera apps, they have alot of ads and keep running so my phone slow down.

Answer (score 1):

You could always download a new Camera app, like openCamera or Google Camera, that would include the volume as shutter function, if the camera app that came with the phone does not have it.

Answer (score -1):

just visit this link, it's worked for me http://indahpurngrm.blogspot.com/2016/04/how-to-use-volume-key-to-take-picture.html?spref=tw

In summary: root your phone and install Xposed Framework and then the Xposed Additions module. From that module you can intercept the volume up key and make it take a screenshot.

Comment: a LOT of work for a "simple" request, haha!

Probably not for the average user.

Answer (score -2):

I have the simplest way for you. Try this :

- Open a camera app.
- Tap a cogwheel icon to enter the setting menu.
- Scroll down to find volume key option, then tap it.
- Select the camera key option.
- Go back to the camera screen .
- Now your ready to use volume down to click a picture.

Comment: this wont work, because, you wont find  out "volume key option", there is no option like that.