# How to assign the volume key for clicking pic in Samsung Galaxy Tab 3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab

Please help, i have a samsung galaxy tab 3 and i want to assign my volume keys for clicking pics when the camera is switched on and thank you in advance

Comment: Which Android version and camera app are you using? It already seems to do that in Lollipop and Marshmallow, but maybe it is the feature of camera app in particular. Is the Android rooted?

Comment: Related: [How to use volume key to take picture in Samsung S3 (with android 4.2)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/129310) and  [Camera app that can use hardware buttons for making photo](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/57412)

Answer (score 0):

Default behavior on a Galaxy S4 (likely the same on a Tab 3) is to use the volume as zoom, but you can change that in settings for the camera app.  Open the camera app, tap the gear icon, then tap gear again, and finally select the gear tab (this is the order in my Lollipop S4; may differ in detail on Kit-Kat or Marshmallow).  One entry is "Volume Key" and you have the option to select "zoom" or "take picture".