# How to create a hardware shortcuts in Android 4.3?

Tags: hardware, samsung-galaxy-s-4, keyboard-shortcuts

I have Samsung Galaxy S4 GT-i9500 running the latest firmware with Android 4.3.

I want to create "hardware shortcuts".

For example, if I hold <kbd>volume up</kbd> and <kbd>home</kbd> at the same time, then it'll open an application that I set, for example "Firefox".

As a Linux user, I know it's possible in Fedora and Ubuntu.

Is it possible with Android? My device has not been rooted.

Comment: The question is similar to [How to assign a hardware button to camera?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48388/how-to-assign-a-hardware-button-to-camera)

Answer (score 0):

From the description, it seems like [Button Savior Non Root](http://www.appbrain.com/app/button-savior-non-root/com.smart.swkey.nonroot) can do this (and [Button Savior (Root)](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Button-Savior-Root/com.smart.swkey) even more). I didn't try it, and the description is slightly unclear whether it only *emulates* hardware keys using a floating menu, or you can re-map hardware keys; so your feedback is welcome if you try it.

Alternatively, the XDA developers offer an app called [ButtonRemapper](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=850464). While this explicitly states *Tool to remap the hardware buttons*, it requires root.

Last partly alternative I can name is [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker). Here I know for sure you can remap at least the camera button. Not sure about others.

Comment: Button Savior can only emulate hardware buttons by creating a kind of auto hide dock on the right side of the screen from where you can select a function like phone, camera, etc.

Comment: With Tasker I found that you can only reconfigure the Camera key. You can not bind actions to combinations like `Volume Up+Home`.

Comment: With ButtonRemapper (ROOT) you can redefine what the hardware buttons do but you still can't configure button combinations like the OP asked.

Comment: Ah – thanks for the feedback. Wasn't sure about *Button Saviour* (note to self: remember). As for *Tasker*: OK, so that didn't change. I had hoped it was added meanwhile, as often requested. Not specifically for combos, but at least for "more keys". That leaves only the "root needed" variant of *ButtonRemapper* – unless someone comes up with a way to "capture the key events" in another way. // I took the combination just as an example; but you may be right with that. I still will leave my answer, might be useful for others at least (I hope).

Comment: I too feel that Tasker should provide more key options but we can come close using AutoInput now. I came very close if not emulated perfectly here: [How to create a hardware shortcuts in Android 4.3?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/123086) :D

Answer (score 0):

You could try [HomeSmack](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=827288) or [Home2 Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eikatou0.appspot.home2shortcut). These apps can remap the functionality of the home button to any app. With the second you can also set up combinations like `Home key` followed by `Search key`, `Back key`, etc. to launch an app.

Answer (score 0):

My almost exact answer was originally posted for the question [Bind action to hardware key combination](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/123018/96277).

---

I've come close but I still can't launch an action at the same time when two keys are pressed in combination like the way we do for taking a screenshot. Anyhow, you would need:

- [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput) (for Android 4.3 and above) with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), both are/have paid/7-day full trial, or
- [Xposed Additions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb&hl=en) (needs root access) with Tasker  to make key combination(s).

The inconvenience in this solution is that unlike pressing both keys at the same time you would have to do it in sequence. That is, press/hold Vol Up followed by Power button. The timing between these key-presses is flexible.

### Single key-press

Use AutoInput with Tasker if you want to launch your action with single  key presses combination i.e. only press a key one time but don't want to long-press the keys.

1. In Tasker create an **Event** based profile from **Plugin →  AutoInput →  Key → Configuration**:

   - **Keys**: **Volume Up**
   - **Key Action**: **Key Down**
2. Create a task in it named "`AutoInput Volume Up`" and create following actions in it:

   1. **Variable → Variable Set**:

      - **Name**: `%Kset`
      - **To**: `1`
   2. **Task → Wait → Seconds**: `1`
   3. Variable → Variable Set:

      - **Name**: `%Kset`
      - **To**: `0`

   **Explanation**: When the single Vol Up press is detected the custom variable `%Kset` would be initialized to a custom value `1` and then we would wait for one second (under this one second you would've to press the Power key). We're then initializing the variable to `0` because our solution demands it, otherwise, our main task of capturing a photo would be executed just by  a single press of Power key.
3. Repeat *step 1* but select **Power** key instead of **Volume Up** key.
4. Create a task in it named "`AutoInput Power`" and create following actions in it:

   1. **Task → If → Condition**: `%Kset` eq `1`
   2. **Plugin → AutoInput  → Modes**:

      - **Configuration**:

        - **Key Suppress**: **Enable**
        - **Keys: Power**
      - **Timeout: None**
   3. Optional action -- **Alert → Flash → Text**: `Commencing launch`
   4. **App → Launch App** → Firefox**.
   5. Repeat *sub-step 2* of *step 4* but do **Key Suppress: Disable**.
   6. Optional action -- **Task → Else**.
   7. Optional action -- **Alert → Flash → Text**: `Psst: You're too late Jim!`

   **Explanation**:

   - In our first action we are checking whether the variable `%Kset` is set to 1 and if yes then the second action would block Power button press from getting passed to system since normally Power key-press would put the device to sleep and lock the screen.
   - Optionally flash a custom toast signalling that combination was successful.
   - Tasker would launch the Firefox or the chosen app successfully.
   - Disable Power key suppress since otherwise, you would never be able to use that button normally, as long as key suppress is not explicitly disabled  or AutoInput's accessibility is running.
   - Else statement is optional but could come handy since in the beginning your consecutive key-presses may not be in coordination so the custom toast in next action would hint you that the combination wasn't successful.

That's it. Go to Home screen or to any non-Tasker app, press the Vol Up key and then the Power key under a time period of one second (don't worry, you would get a hang of it, or else, change the wait period) and you would see Tasker opening its custom interface, a picture would be captured automatically and you would be taken back to what you're originally doing.

Hurray!

---

### Long key-press

Some people may not like single pressing both the keys since they are not habitual or may feel odd to use them in that coordination. In that case, provided that you've root access and [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/) installed, you can use **Xposed Additions** to set long key-press actions for your keys.

For custom action to be set to those keys we would need **Tasker**. Create the two tasks named "`AutoInput Volume Up`" and "`AutoInput Power`" explicitly in Tasker, only if you didn't follow **Single key-press** section.

1. In that app go to **Button** → set **Long press delay** time → **Add new key** → tap **Vol Up key** → select the new key entry.
2. Tap **Add new Condition**  → **Screen On** → → select the new entry → check **Long Press** and tap on that entry  → scroll down to **Shortcut** → **Task Shortcut** → **AutoInput Volume Up**.
3. Repeat *step 1* but do it for **Power** key.
4. Repeat *step 2* but select **AutoInput Power** under **Task Shortcut**.

Whenever Xposed Additions is enabled and activated in Xposed Framework, on any long-press of a button/key set under that app, you would feel a slight vibration. That vibration would help immensely to know when to release the first key and long-press the other key.

Try it because it's fun.