# Change mapping of Hardware buttons in an un-rooted device?

Tags: hardware, buttons

How can I change the mapping of my un-rooted device's buttons like swapping the volume buttons? My device is a Sony Xperia E C1505

Comment: Can you provide more information about what phone you have, and whether or not you're rooted or willing to be rooted?

Comment: About rooting: no. Not because I do not want to(I do really want to root it), but because the build.prop has been tampered, by my friend. The only plus is that no games are incompatible work.

Comment: My understanding is that the only way to remap buttons is with root.

Comment: I did, see this link [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/142203?noredirect=1)

Comment: @Firelord well, I have root now (apparently, king root changed how they work) so that's sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why would you want to swap those buttons but you can certainly do it using [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput) (for Android 4.3 and above), [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), both are/have paid/7-day full trial, [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) (free/paid) and [Shortcut Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mibi.shortcutlauncher)/ [AutoShortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoshortcut&hl=en) (free/paid).

1. After installing **Shortcut Launcher** you would see four icons namely **Shortcut 1**, **Shortcut 2**, and so on in your app drawer.

   Tap **Shortcut 1 → MacroDroid Shortcut → `<Add New Macro>` → Volume Up/Down → Volume Down** → proceed → ignore **Add Constraints** → name it "`Volume Down`".
2. Similarly, assign a MacrDroid shortcut to **Shortcut 2** but choose **Volume Up** and name it "`Volume Up`".

   Alternatively, AutoShortcut can be used in place of Shortcut Launcher. Use it in a Tasker's task to directly access a MacroDroid shortcut. It is available under **Plugin**.
3. In Tasker create an **Event** based profile from **Plugin →  AutoInput →  Key → Configuration**:

   - **Keys**: **Volume Up**
   - **Key Action**: **Key Down**
4. Create a task and add following actions:

   1. **Plugin → AutoInput  → Modes**:

      - **Configuration**:

        - **Key Suppress**: **Enable**
        - **Keys: Volume Up**
      - **Timeout: None**
   2. **App → Launch App → Shortcut 1**
5. Create another **Event** based profile but for **Volume Down** (follow *step 3*)
6. Repeat *step 4*  but under *sub-step 1* do **Keys: Volume Down** and assign the app **Shortcut 2** in *sub-step 2* there.

That's it. It's not completely flawless but the flaws can be ignored.

For any reasoning about related to AutoInput see my answer at [Bind action to hardware key combination](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/123018/96277).

Comment: I just noticed that your device probably did not receive Android 4.3 so this answer may not be helpful to you, but it is still good for anyone having Android 4.3 or above.

Comment: i know, but I can still work with it.